# Can Git diff parameters improve source code change alignment?

Tags: java, git, git-diff

Adding annotated functions to an existing source file produces mis-aligned diffs. For example, consider adding the `provideNewThing` method:

```
@Provides
Foo provideFoo() {...}

@Provides
NewThing provideNewThing() {...} 

@Provides
Bar provideBar() {...}
```

Running `git diff` on the command line will show:

```
     @Provides
     Foo provideFoo() {...}

     @Provides
+    NewThing provideNewThing() {...}
+
+    @Provides
     Bar provideBar() {...}
```

This is not ideal. *It appears I've introduced the @Provides annotation to `provideBar`*. A closer look shows otherwise, but it's easy to miss.

Ideally there is a `git diff <some-options>` which outputs:

```
     @Provides
     Foo provideFoo() {...}
+
+    @Provides
+    NewThing provideNewThing() {...}

     @Provides
     Bar provideBar() {...}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried `git diff --diff-algorithm=patience` ?

Comment: Yes, the diff algorithms offered by git behave the same for this example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sometimes diff alignment can be difficult to identify. In this case it is simple, but I have encountered scenarios I need to keep track of what was added where. I use kdiff3 - [Manual diff alignment](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/doc/interpretinginformation.html#manualdiffhelp).

To add manual diff alignment in KDiff3:

- Select text in one child window
- Hit Ctrl+Y
- Select text in another child window
- Hit Ctrl+Y

[image: Illustration]

Notice the diff alignment in the screenshot attached.

Comment: I've toyed with the idea of configuring a windowed diff tool for quick reviews; it never seems worthwhile. For big reviews, this manual diff alignment feature rocks!